# Does anybody know what means ShellHook message HSHELL_RUDEAPPACTIVATED?

Tags: c#, winapi, shell, windows-vista, message

I am writing application which establishes shell hooks to get shell events (I am using C# if it matters).
I am using this example: http://msbob.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!DAFD19BC5D669D8F!132.entry

Hook is working fine but I do not receive message on which I am interested: HSHELL_WINDOWACTIVATED (all other window-related events work well).
Instead I am receiving message with code 32772 which should be HSHELL_RUDEAPPACTIVATED (some googling helped).

But I can't understand why I am not receiving HSHELL_WINDOWACTIVATED at all and what this HSHELL_RUDEAPPACTIVATED message means. MSDN does not have any mention of it. 
Can anybody explain it to me?

Answer (score 7):

`HSHELL_RUDEAPPACTIVATED` is 32772, which is just `HSHELL_WINDOWACTIVATED` with the high bit set.  From what little I can glean on various Web sites, it appears that Windows sends this message when a full screen app is activated.  Kind of hard to tell for sure.

Have you tried treating that message the same as `HSHELL_WINDOWACTIVATED'?

Comment: Yes, now I am treating it as HSHELL_WINDOWACTIVATED and all works fine. But I want to understand why this message is rising. It comes from any window, not only full screen apps.