# How to activate a function everytime the target window becomes active in AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to activate a sound profile every time I switch to a specific program and change back to the default profile every time I leave it. 
This action is turned on in a GUI via a radio button.

The workaround I have created is:

```
Auto_Ftsps:
    gui, Submit, NoHide
    While (Rad3==1)
    {
        Previous_window:= WinActive("A")
        Sleep,1000
        Current_window:= WinActive("A")
        If (Previous_window =Current_window)
            {}
        Else If (Previous_window !=Current_window) 
        {
            If(WinActive("Fortnite"))
                Run_Peace_Profile("Ftsps")
            Else 
                Run_Peace_Profile("Graphic EQ")
        }
        Sleep,2000
    }
    return
```

Is there a better way to do this? I looked on forums and tutorials with no success.

Comment: https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=6463

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OnWin.ahk is somewhat similar to your method; it uses [`SetTimer`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) to periodically check for the events you register with it, so unlike your method it's asynchronous in terms of AHK threads. Don't quote me on this, but I think internally [`WinWaitActive`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWaitActive.htm) is similar as well.

There is however another way that doesn't involve periodically checking the active window ourselves and instead allows us to react to Windows' "active window change" events - a shell hook. Typically [`SetWindowsHookEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) with `WH_SHELL` would be used for this, but I don't think it's even possible to use it with AHK alone (you have to make a DLL), and it's kind of complicated to get everything right. Luckily there's [`RegisterShellHookWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx), which allows us to receive shell events as Windows messages rather than injecting a DLL into other threads. We can then use AHK's [`OnMessage`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/OnMessage.htm) to react to these messages, which, in your case, means having a function that tests for to `wParam` being `HSHELL_WINDOWACTIVATED` or `HSHELL_RUDEAPPACTIVATED` (i.e., bit 3 is set) and changes the sound profile accordingly. As for turning this functionality on/off, we can have the radio buttons' g-label contain the logic for controlling whether we want to receive the shell messages via `(De)RegisterShellHookWindow`.

```
#SingleInstance Force

Gui +AlwaysOnTop +HwndhWnd
Gui Add, Text,, Automatic sound profile change
Gui Add, Radio, gHookRadioHandler Checked, On
Gui Add, Radio, gHookRadioHandler X+, Off
Gui Font,, Consolas
Gui Add, Edit, HwndhLog xm w800 r30 ReadOnly -Wrap -WantReturn

ftspsActive := false

; Get the dynamic identifier for shell messages and assign our callback to handle these messages
SHELL_MSG := DllCall("RegisterWindowMessage", "Str", "SHELLHOOK", "UInt")
OnMessage(SHELL_MSG, Func("ShellCallback"))

if (!SetHook(true)) {
    GuiControl,, Off, 1
}

Gui Show


GuiClose() {
    ExitApp
}

; Dummy implementation that logs the changes to an edit control for demonstration purposes
Run_Peace_Profile(profile) {
    Println("Switched to " profile)
}

; Sets whether the shell hook is registered
SetHook(state) {
    global hWnd
    static shellHookInstalled := false
    if (!shellHookInstalled and state) {
        if (!DllCall("RegisterShellHookWindow", "Ptr", hWnd)) {
            Println("Failed to register shell hook")
            return false
        }
        Println("Registered shell hook")
        shellHookInstalled := true
    }
    else if (shellHookInstalled and !state) {
        if (!DllCall("DeregisterShellHookWindow", "Ptr", hWnd)) {
            Println("Failed to deregister shell hook")
            return false
        }
        Println("Deregistered shell hook")
        shellHookInstalled := false
    }

    return true
}

; Radio button handler that controls registration of the sound profile hook
HookRadioHandler() {
    state := A_GuiControl == "On"
    if (!SetHook(state)) {
        GuiControl,, % (state ? "Off" : "On"), 1
    }
}

; Shell messages callback
ShellCallback(wParam, lParam) {
    ; HSHELL_WINDOWACTIVATED = 4, HSHELL_RUDEAPPACTIVATED = 0x8004
    if (wParam & 4) {
        ; lParam = hWnd of activated window
        global ftspsActive
        WinGet fnHWnd, ID, Fortnite

        WinGetTitle t, ahk_id %lParam%
        Println("active window: " t)

        if (!ftspsActive and fnHWnd = lParam) {
            Run_Peace_Profile("Ftsps")
            ftspsActive := true
        }
        else if (ftspsActive and fnHWnd != lParam) {
            Run_Peace_Profile("Graphic EQ")
            ftspsActive := false
        }
    }
}

; Prints a line to the logging edit box
Println(s) {
    global hLog
    static MAX_LINES := 1000, LINE_ADJUST := 200, nLines := 0
    ; EM_SETSEL = 0xB1, EM_REPLACESEL = 0xC2, EM_LINEINDEX = 0xBB
    if (nLines = MAX_LINES) {
        ; Delete the oldest LINE_ADJUST lines
        SendMessage 0xBB, LINE_ADJUST,,, ahk_id %hLog%
        SendMessage 0xB1, 0, ErrorLevel,, ahk_id %hLog%
        SendMessage 0xC2, 0, 0,, ahk_id %hLog%
        nLines -= LINE_ADJUST
    }
    ++nLines
    ; Move to the end by selecting all and deselecting
    SendMessage 0xB1, 0, -1,, ahk_id %hLog%
    SendMessage 0xB1, -1, -1,, ahk_id %hLog%
    ; Add the line
    str := "[" A_Hour ":" A_Min "] " s "`r`n"
    SendMessage 0xC2, 0, &str,, ahk_id %hLog%
}
```

Note that I added some feedback messages in the form of an edit control just so this script can serve as a small stand-alone demonstration.

A possible drawback of this approach comes right from the top of the `RegisterShellHookWindow` documentation:

> This function is not intended for general use. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions of Windows.

Additionally, I have no idea what a "rude app" is or why they have their own constant. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178020/does-anybody-know-what-means-shellhook-message-hshell-rudeappactivated) says it has to do with full-screen applications, but the asker and I receive `HSHELL_RUDEAPPACTIVATED` for seemingly every program.

As an alternative, there's also [`SetWinEventHook`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx), which can be called with `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND` and `WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT` to install a callback from AHK which is called every time the foreground window changes. Note that this will be called for child windows coming to the foreground, unlike the `RegisterShellHookWindow` method.

```
#SingleInstance Force

Gui +AlwaysOnTop
Gui Add, Text,, Automatic sound profile change
Gui Add, Radio, gHookRadioHandler Checked, On
Gui Add, Radio, gHookRadioHandler X+, Off
Gui Font,, Consolas
Gui Add, Edit, HwndhLog xm w800 r30 ReadOnly -Wrap -WantReturn

ftspsActive := false

fcAddr := RegisterCallback(Func("FgCallback"))

if (!SetHook(true)) {
    GuiControl,, Off, 1
}

Gui Show


GuiClose() {
    ExitApp
}

; Dummy implementation that logs the changes to an edit control for demonstration purposes
Run_Peace_Profile(profile) {
    Println("Switched to " profile)
}

; Sets whether the foreground hook is installed
SetHook(state) {
    global fcAddr
    static hook, fgHookInstalled := false

    if (!fgHookInstalled and state) {
        ; EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND = 3, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0
        hook := DllCall("SetWinEventHook", "UInt", 3, "UInt", 3, "Ptr", 0, "Ptr", fcAddr, "Int", 0, "Int", 0, "UInt", 0, "Ptr")
        if (!hook) {
            Println("Failed to set foreground hook")
            return false
        }
        Println("Set foreground hook")
        fgHookInstalled := true
    }
    else if (fgHookInstalled and !state) {
        if (!DllCall("UnhookWinEvent", "Ptr", hook)) {
            Println("Failed to unset foreground hook")
            return false
        }
        Println("Unset foreground hook")
        fgHookInstalled := false
    }

    return true
}

; Radio button handler that controls installation of the sound profile hook
HookRadioHandler() {
    state := A_GuiControl == "On"
    if (!SetHook(state)) {
        GuiControl,, % (state ? "Off" : "On"), 1
    }
}

; Foreground window change callback
FgCallback(hWinEventHook, event, hWnd, idObject, idChild, dwEventThread, dwmsEventTime) {
    global ftspsActive
    WinGet fnHWnd, ID, Fortnite

    WinGetTitle t, ahk_id %hWnd%
    Println("fg window: " t)

    if (!ftspsActive and fnHWnd = hWnd) {
        Run_Peace_Profile("Ftsps")
        ftspsActive := true
    }
    else if (ftspsActive and fnHWnd != hWnd) {
        Run_Peace_Profile("Graphic EQ")
        ftspsActive := false
    }
}

; Prints a line to the logging edit box
Println(s) {
    global hLog
    static MAX_LINES := 1000, LINE_ADJUST := 200, nLines := 0
    ; EM_SETSEL = 0xB1, EM_REPLACESEL = 0xC2, EM_LINEINDEX = 0xBB
    if (nLines = MAX_LINES) {
        ; Delete the oldest LINE_ADJUST lines
        SendMessage 0xBB, LINE_ADJUST,,, ahk_id %hLog%
        SendMessage 0xB1, 0, ErrorLevel,, ahk_id %hLog%
        SendMessage 0xC2, 0, 0,, ahk_id %hLog%
        nLines -= LINE_ADJUST
    }
    ++nLines
    ; Move to the end by selecting all and deselecting
    SendMessage 0xB1, 0, -1,, ahk_id %hLog%
    SendMessage 0xB1, -1, -1,, ahk_id %hLog%
    ; Add the line
    str := "[" A_Hour ":" A_Min "] " s "`r`n"
    SendMessage 0xC2, 0, &str,, ahk_id %hLog%
}
```

Comment: Hey, this works amazingly but I don't fully understand how it works. I am trying to make it so it turns on by default.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; do you mean you want the script to automatically run when your computer boots up?

Comment: No when you run this script the default mode on the UI is Off. I wanted it to be on as soon as the program opens. I made a work around but it is very geto.

Comment: Gotcha - I edited the answer. I moved the hook installation logic to a function separate from the hook handler, which can then be called at script startup to install the hook.