# Log multiple Keys with AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I´m trying to let a race game play via AutoHotkey. I use this script to paste the keys i pressed into a txt to let them automaticly play back.

My problem is now that this script only can log one key, for example {w down} for drive forward. But to drive in the game better you must press <kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>d</kbd> to drive to the right.

How can I change the code to make it work the way I want?

```
$F1::
start := A_TickCount
FileDelete, log.txt

Loop
{
Input, key, L1 V, %endkeyslist%
IfInString, ErrorLevel, EndKey:
{
StringTrimleft, key, ErrorLevel, 7
}
time := (A_TickCount - start)
start := A_TickCount
text1:="Sleep, " time "`n"
text2:="Send {" key " Down} `n"
FileAppend, %text1%, log.txt
FileAppend, %text2%, log.txt

KeyWait, %key% ;waits the key to be released
time := (A_TickCount - start)
start := A_TickCount
text1:="Sleep, " time "`n"
text2:="Send {" key " Up} `n"
FileAppend, %text1%, log.txt
FileAppend, %text2%, log.txt
}
return

$F2:: ExitApp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `OnMessage()` to monitor both key-down (0x100) and key-up (0x101) event messages. Here are some links to the pertinent help documentation: [OnMessage()](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/OnMessage.htm), [List of Windows Messages](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/SendMessageList.htm).

Below is a working example that will make a file on your desktop `testEE.txt` with similar parameters to what you're logging. Note that this will not log mouse movements or clicks (it is possible, I just didn't set it up that way). Press `F1` to start and stop recording.

```
f1::
bT := !bT
If bT
{
    MsgBox ,,, Recording started , 1
    KeyBdHook := DllCall(   "SetWindowsHookEx" , "int" , 13  , "uint" , RegisterCallback( "KeyBdProc" ) , "uint" , 0 , "uint" , 0 )
    nStart := A_TickCount
} Else {
    DllCall( "UnhookWindowsHookEx" , "ptr" , KeyBdHook )
    MsgBox ,,, Recording terminated , 1
}
Return

KeyBdProc( nCode , wParam , lParam )
{
    global
    Critical
    If ( wParam = 0x100 || wParam = 0x101 )
    {
        nKey := Format( "{:x}" , NumGet( lParam + 0 , 0 , "int" ) )
        nTime := A_TickCount - nStart , nStart := A_TickCount
        If ( wParam = 0x100 && nKey != nKeyPrev )
        {
            nKeyPrev := nKey
            FileAppend , % nTime . "|" . nKey . " down`n" , %A_Desktop%/testEE.txt
        }
        If ( wParam = 0x101 )
        {
            If ( nKey = nKeyPrev )
                nKeyPrev := ""
            FileAppend , % nTime . "|" . nKey . " up`n" , %A_Desktop%/testEE.txt
    }   }
    Return DllCall( "CallNextHookEx" , "uint" , KeyBdHook , "int" , nCode , "uint" , wParam , "uint" , lParam )
}
```

This will replay your keypresses:

```
f2::
aData := []
FileRead , sText , %A_Desktop%/testEE.txt
Loop , Parse , sText , `n , `r
{
    nCt := A_Index
    Loop , Parse , A_LoopField , |
        aData[ nCt , A_Index ] := A_LoopField
}
Loop , % aData.Length()
{
    If InStr( aData[ A_Index , 2 ] , "70 " ) ; 0x70 is F1
        Continue
    Sleep , % aData[ A_Index , 1 ]
    Send , % "{vk" . aData[ A_Index , 2 ] . "}"
}
Return
```

Note that it also records the hotkey that starts and stops recording, so I made it `Continue` if it sees this key. If you change the hotkey to some other key or key-combination, you'll need to set it to ignore that key or key-combination instead.

I found these posts especially helpful, for reference:
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/27067-mouse-move-detection/
https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=11922
[How to activate a function everytime the target window becomes active in AutoHotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610663/how-to-activate-a-function-everytime-the-target-window-becomes-active-in-autohot)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-unhookwindowshookex

Comment: Thx for yoru fast help :D . But this didnt fix my problem... i need to achiev that i can log multiple Keypress at once or that i automaticly format it like that:                 
Sleep, 31
Send {65 Down} {68 Down}
Sleep, 31
Send {65 Up} {68 Up}                                                                            tell me when i didnt get it

Comment: @Broump No problem. This does log multiple key presses at once, but it doesn't format it exactly like you had it. This was just an example of how to use `OnMessage()`. To make the formatting how you want it, you'll need to translate the `wParam` to the virtual key number (`KeyHistory` can help you discover each key's code) and add the extra text as you have it (specifically, `text1` and `text2`).

Comment: Oh thx , now i´m seeing it :). How do you mean the translation? The KeyHistory gives me different numbers than your script... . Could it work using a if-Statement like this: if (wPd == 87) {
  key = "w"
       }                            or must i use a different technique? Thx for help

Comment: @Broump By translation, I meant to convert it from decimal to hexadecimal. I updated the code and added another portion that will read it. I believe it is totally functional for what you need now.

Comment: But it only logs the keys when the gui is active... . I need to switch to the game and there the script doesnt log anything...

Comment: @Broump Understood. This turned out to be much more challenging than I expected, but after a bit of research and some very helpful info from Lexicos I think I got it. I updated the code. Please let me know if that works for you.