# while loop not executing correctly when toggled on/off

Tags: autohotkey

Goals:

Run ahk script so that a window stays active. When the user clicks off the window it immediately becomes active again.

This is so an overlay (considered its own window) can be used in a game and that if the overlay is clicked on by accident the game window will become the active window again.

I would also like this to be able to be turned on and off during game play so that the user can alt+tab if necessary.

Problems:

I'm testing my code implementation, so far i have it set up to make a blank notepad file become the active window and stay active.

The problem is the toggle (ctrl+alt+J). I can toggle the code it off just fine but when i toggle it on the window doesn't become active again.

Code:

```
stop := 0
; 0 = off, 1 = on

while (stop = 0)
{
    IfWinNotActive, Untitled - Notepad
        {
        WinActivate, Untitled - Notepad
        }
}

return

^!j::
    stop  := !stop

    if (stop = 0){
        MsgBox, stop is off.
    }
    else{
        MsgBox, stop is  on.
    }

return
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work after you toggle it off is that `While` only runs *until* is evaluates to false. Even if what it would evaluate later becomes true again, it won't restart.
Here's what you can do to make your current code work:

```
stop := 0
; 0 = off, 1 = on

labelWinCheck: ; label for GoSub to restart while-loop
while (stop = 0)
{
    IfWinNotActive, Untitled - Notepad
    {
        WinActivate, Untitled - Notepad
    }
    Sleep , 250 ; added sleep (250 ms) so CPU isn't running full blast
}
return

^!j::
    stop  := !stop

    if (stop = 0){
        MsgBox, stop is off.
    } else {
        MsgBox, stop is on.
    }
GoSub , labelWinCheck ; restarts while-loop
return
```

There are a couple of different ways that I would look at to achieve your goal.

- Easy: use `SetTimer` instead of While.

```
stop := 0
SetTimer , labelWinCheck , 250 ; Repeats every 250 ms

labelWinCheck:
If !WinActive( "Untitled - Notepad" )
    WinActivate , Untitled - Notepad
Return

^!j::
SetTimer , labelWinCheck , % ( stop := !stop ) ? "off" : "on"
MsgBox , % "stop is " . ( stop ? "on" : "off" )
Return
```

- Advanced: us `OnMessage()` to monitor WinActivate events. I don't have a working example of this as that would take a bit of research for me, but here is a link for a solution I made to monitor keyboard events, [Log multiple Keys with AutoHotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55578584/log-multiple-keys-with-autohotkey). The links at the bottom may especially prove useful.