# How to detect all special buttons, entered by user, using AHK:

Tags: autohotkey

I have written a code that print each key stroke ,user made, in txt file, then i need as well to detect special characters user entered, such as (Enter, Alt, ctrl, and so on), How to do that, my code is attached below:

```
A:=0
Loop {    
    str1 := "" A    
    Input, str1, L1          
    FileAppend,%str1% `n, %A_WorkingDir%\keyboard.txt 
    A++    
}
```

Comment: Keyloggers are generally frowned upon in the AutoHotkey community...

Comment: @Spyre Are they? There are certainly many non-nefarious applications. Here is a keylogger/replayer hotkey that may work for OP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55578584/log-multiple-keys-with-autohotkey

Comment: If this were the AHK forums, I would ask OP what his intended use-case of the logger is and design a script tailor-made for that task. 

As this is StackOverflow, I can't quite ask that question (since OP technically did provide all of the info needed to solve their issue), so the best alternative that I can see is not answering the question.

Although there are certainly ethical uses of keyloggers ([such as this example](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/73858-looking-for-efficient-key-logger-script/)), I have found them few and far between.

Just my thoughts, so take it as you will.